# fancybox doesnt work in IE8 but works normally in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

When using ie9, fancybox window opens normally but in IE8 it doesn't work; it will redirect to the page URL instead of loading it in fancybox.

The code is normal, nothing special:

```
$("a.iframe").fancybox({
    'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'width'         :   '70%',
    'height'        :   '80%'

});

<a class="iframe" href="ResultsLogin.aspx">View Results</a>
```

Please assist if this is a know issue and if it has a fix.

Comment: You have a spare comma on your settings object. Remove the comma after `'80%'`

Comment: Removed it, but its not in the source page code

Comment: Check that you have a proper DOCTYPE

Comment: I  have the same issue. Looking for a fix. Just the same setup as you have there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing comma on the last attribute. IE8 thinks there is something to come after it and breaks. Modern browsers will most likely understand what you have done and get on with the the rest of the script.

```
'height'        :   '80%',
```

Comment: Double check you have the fancybox CSS stylesheet loading in your and also ensure your javascript files are loading in the correct order i.e. jQuery library, fancybox library and then your fancybox config settings etc.